# Including Exception in python

Tags: python

I have a file at /location/all-list-info.txt underneath I have some items in below manner:

> aaa:xxx:abc.com:1857:xxx1:rel5t2:y
>
> ifa:yyy:xyz.com:1858:yyy1:rel5t2:y

I process these items with a below python code:

```
def pITEMName():

        global itemList
        itemList = str(raw_input('Enter pipe separated list of ITEMS : ')).upper().strip()
        items = itemList.split("|")
        count = len(items)
        print  'Total Distint Item Count : ',  count
        pipelst = itemList.split('|')
        filepath = '/location/all-item-info.txt '
        f = open(filepath, 'r')
        for lns in f:
                split_pipe = lns.split(':', 1)
                if split_pipe[0] in pipelst:
                        index = pipelst.index(split_pipe[0])
                        del pipelst[index]

        for lns in pipelst:
            print lns,' is wrong item Name'

        f.close()
        if podList:
```

After execution of above python code its gives a prompt as :

> Enter pipe separated list of ITEMS:

And then I passes the items :

> Enter pipe separated list of ITEMS: aaa|ifa-mc|ggg-mc

now after pressing enter above code process further like below :

> Enter pipe separated list of ITEMS : aaa|ifa-mc|ggg-mc
>
> Total Distint Item Count :  3
>
> IFA-MC  is wrong Item Name
>
> GGG-MC  is wrong Item Name
>
> ITEMs Belonging to other Centers :
>
> Item Count From Other Center =  0
>
> ITEMs Belonging to Current Centers :
>
> Active Items in  US1 :
>
> ^IFA$
>
> Test Active Items in  US1 :
>
> ^AAA$
>
> Ignored Item Count From Current center =  0
>
> You Have Entered ItemList belonging to this center as: ^IFA$|^AAA$
>
> Active Pod Count :  2

My question is if I suffix the '-mc' in items while giving the input its given me as wrong item whereas it presents in /location/all-item-info.txt file with not present the item in /location/all-item-info.txt . Please have a look at below output again :

> IFA-MC  is wrong Item Name
>
> GGG-MC  is wrong Item Name

In above example 'ifa' is present in /location/all-items-info.txt path whereas as ggg is not present.
Request you to help me here what can I do on above code so if I suffix the -mc which are present in /location/all-items-info.txt file it should not count as wrong item name. it should count only for those items which are not present in /location/all-items-info.txt file.

Please give you help.

Thanks,
Ritesh.

Comment: is `ifa-mc` specifically present in the `all-items-info.txt` if not that is the reason, you are not removing -mc from the list to check only for `ifa` , is the require ment to check only for `ifa` not `ifa-mc` ?

Comment: Anand, I am require to check both ifa and ifa-mc, if ifa present in file it should not show IFA-MC is wrong item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid checking for `-mc` as well, then you can modify this part of your script -

```
pipelst = itemList.split('|')
```

To -

```
pipelst = [i.split('-')[0] for i in itemList.split('|')]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Anand. It works for me. I exactly just wanted to avoid -mc.

Comment: if you just want to avoid `-mc` then instead of `i.split('-')` in the above code, you shuold use - `i.split('-mc')`

Comment: Thanks Anand. 95% hint you have given in your above code. So I have done as it is as you have mentioned just above. Its working now :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear exactly what you are asking, but basically to ignore any '-mc' from user input, you can explicitly preprocess the user input to strip it out:

```
pipelst = itemList.split('|')
pipelst = [item.rsplit('-mc',1)[0] for item in pipelst]
```

If instead you want to allow for the possibility of -mc-suffixed words in the file as well, simply add the stripped version to the list instead of replacing

```
pipelst = itemList.split('|')
for item in pipelist:
    if item.endswith('-mc'):
        pipelst.append(item.rsplit('-mc',1)[0])
```

Another issue may be based on the example lines you gave from `/location/all-list-info.txt`, it sounds like all the items are lowercase.  However, `pipelst` is explicitly making the user input all uppercase.  String equality and `in` mechanics *is* case-sensitive, so for instance

```
>>> print 'ifa-mc' in ['IFA-MC']
False
```

You probably want:

```
itemList = str(raw_input('Enter pipe separated list of ITEMS : ')).lower().strip()
```

and you could use `.upper()` only when printing or wherever it is needed

Finally, there are a few other things that could be tweaked with the code just to make things a bit faster and cleaner.  The main one that comes to mind is it seems like `pipelst` should be a [python set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) and not a list as checking inclusion and removal would then be much faster for large lists, and the code to remove an item from a set is much cleaner:

```
>>> desserts = set(['ice cream', 'cookies', 'cake'])
>>> if 'cake' in desserts:
...     desserts.remove('cake')
>>> print desserts
set(['cookies', 'ice cream'])
```

Comment: Hi Lemonhead, I am not getting any difference while appending your 2nd code.Exaclty I want the same which you have mentioned in your 2ns statement. I want to give ifa or ifa-mc, it should show as wrong item rather for ggg or ggg-mc should show as wrong item (coz not present in file.) please have look again.